# How to change the text of "More" bar item in a tab bar base iphone application

Tags: iphone

I faced a problem that I can not find a way to change the text of "More" bar item in the tab bar, just like what I can do on other tab bar items. After searching the forum, I only find a way to change the title of the "More" view pushed by "More" button. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

```
UINavigationBar *moreNavigationBar = tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar;
moreNavigationBar.topItem.title = @"More Features";
```

Comment: at where u have written this code ? in viewDidLoad ?

Comment: in AppDelegate, this code is working to change the title of the view. Don't worry about it, I just want to do something more to change the text of the item in the bottom tabbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the default 'More' tab, you won't be able to change that. Apple handles all of the code for this tab behind the scenes. It is designed to give the user the ability to rearrange the order of tabs when you have too many to show in your tab bar controller.

My suggestion would be to not fight this and try to override the 'More' functionality. If you would like a tab called 'More', but want to handle that functionality yourself, then don't use Apple's built in More tab, just find a suitable icon and handle things yourself. Hope this helps.

Comment: But we can change other bar button item textColor on the tab bar

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.  We can change more tab Text name and image also.

```
 [[tabBarControllers.moreNavigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Title" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image Name"] tag:0]]
```